# Drupal block not appearing on CiviMail page

Tags: civimail, drupal

I want to add some inline help to the New mailing CiviMail.  e.g. show a block on this page civicrm/a/#/mailing/12345

I've created my drupal block, set it to appear in the correct theme and set it to only display on this page: civicrm/a/#/mailing/*

However for some reason it won't show.  I've backtracked and I'm able to get it to show up with this expression: civicrm/* but as soon as I add civicrm/a/* it doesn't work, just doesn't display

Any ideas about why this might be?

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 5):

I think this may have something to do with the [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) (#).  This is typically used to link to a particular point within a page (an anchor).  However, in this case I think it is being used by the JavaScript framework to indicate a particular page view.  I guess that Drupal may not be able to process URLs like this.

Comment: hey @William - have you had a chance to reproduce this? As the CiviCRM project is transitioning to AngularJS for all forms - we may need to rethink the # in its urls

Comment: @KarinG-SemperIT I haven't looked into this myself but it would be worth checking it out.  Perhaps best to avoid the # if possible?

Comment: I think you're correct - voted you up! And added a possible immediate workaround for Peter.

Answer (score 4):

I think @William is correct - I just tried and I can't get a Block -> Visibility -> Pages -> Show block on specific pages -> Only the listed pages -> to show up on a #a URL (tried escaping the # - can't do it). civicrm/a* works - but then you'd be seeing it on all forms using AngularJS.

That's not good! Let's search JIRA CiviCRM for it - and if needed report it. I did have a client run into using #a on iOS/Safari - workaround at that time for to use Chrome - but this is a bigger issue.

Possible immediate workaround [I know not ideal]
I suspect that you only have few people who can CiviMail -> put them into a Drupal Role of their own -> then:

- use Region settings to only show this block to your staff in the
  CiviCRM theme
- use visibility settings -> Roles -> Show block for specific roles

Answer (score 3):

Agree with Williams' description.

Other possible resolutions:

1. Give some love and patience to planned updates for the form system. Right now, Angular pages are strictly SPA ("single-page architecture" -- "javascript handles the page routing") and they're not very hookable. Current plans for the next iteration provide more hookability and reduce the reliance on SPA. (Somewhat related: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=36978.0 )
2. Target the block at the base page `civicrm/a`. In the code for your block, use some Javascript to call `setInterval()` and periodically check `window.location.hash`; hide or display the desired block with `$.hide()` or `$.show()`.

Comment: Increase hookability for AngularJS forms: cool; yes I would love that! Ad 2: many Drupal blocks are not generated in code though - we must retain some way for Drupal blocks to be displayed via the Drupal Core -> structure -> blocks GUI - esp if we get to building public Contribution pages with AngularJS - b/c there you'd typically get all sorts of Drupal blocks added to such a CiviCRM page: like eg social media block; search block etc

Comment: Idle curiosity - any reason that the existing architecture of angular pages didn't include different urls? Would it be super difficult to just add in an extra path component after the /civicrm/a/ that is ignored by the angular code?

Comment: That might work for some use-cases. FWIW, though, it would only display Drupal blocks that match the *original* path; when you navigate among different Angular routes (e.g. `civicrm/a/#/abtest` => `civicrm/a/#/abtest/new` => `civicrm/a/#/abtest/1`), that navigation is all client-side, so it would never ask Drupal to rerender the list of blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Taking this in a slightly different direction - it reminds me that in general, CiviCRM urls are not very nice when it comes to Drupal, because Drupal doesn't like to pay attention to query strings. I wonder if there is a broader solution that also deals with this issue? I'd imagined that there's a simple Drupal hook that could so some rewriting in and out.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this so don't know if it will work. But, I create URL aliases for my civicrm contribution pages so that when a user goes to those pages it's a nice pretty url instead of the long civicrm url. I wonder if creating a URL alias in Drupal and then using that alias as the URL for the Show only on this page would work?

Comment: Unfortunately, that will not work - for the same reason (the # in the URL). Also for a new mailing screen - you can't URL alias that as unlike stationary contribution page URLs the id is generated as you create the new mailing: civicrm/a#/mailing/776 and then civicrm/a#/mailing/777 etc.

Comment: I didnt think about the id's changing. blah.